# Adding a custom logic to a Scala's constructor

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a class

```
  class MyClass(a: Int, b: String) {
   //....
  }
```

If I want to add some custom logic (code) to this constructor, how do I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
class MyClass(a: Int, b: String) {
   // this is the constructor right here
   println("Hi, i'm the constructor")

   def imAMethod = 1

   println("Hi, I'm also part of the constructor down here, the whole class body is")
}
```